# How can I test the XML deserialization of a dotnet-core WCF client?

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, .net-core

I've [inherited an existing WCF client](https://github.com/SkillsFundingAgency/dfc-coursedirectory/blob/b7f6600f5ccb3313210faec77797dfe9a74e764b/src/Dfc.CourseDirectory.Core/Connected%20Services/UkrlpService/Reference.cs) built with https://github.com/dotnet/wcf which I now need to modify, and as such [want to get it under test](https://timwise.co.uk/2020/07/09/approaches-to-refactoring-and-technical-debt/) to avoid regressions.

To be clear this is only the client, I do not control the SOAP service I am connecting to.

To get this under test I want to inject a known response from the server (in the form of a fixed XML response) instead of having the service under test connect to the production endpoint. Once I have that I can then validate that the correct values are returned from the generated WCF client.

Is there a hook somewhere I can use with the WCF client to provide the fake XML response? Any other suggestions for how to test the deserialization?

Update: Having failed to find any pure code hooks I'm currently investigating firing up an [`HttpListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener) to server up the the xml and changing the endpoint during testing to point to that.

---

*(also asked here https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4370)*

Comment: When the client communicates with the server, a channel is created. If the xml response is forged, I think the wcf client will not receive this xml.

Comment: I have heard of this "[channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/channel-model-overview)" thing but don't really know what to do with that information.

Comment: What are you really trying to test? Testing deserialization isn't meaningful unless you've discovered a real problem. The WCF client is created by the service's WSDL so it will always match the schemas defined there. Unlike REST, SOAP is based on specific standards, so it *should* be possible to just use any SOAP-compliant service. Unfortunately, some companies choose to ignore those standards, or never bothered to update their services to follow the standards. Think airlines with 15+-year old services

Comment: Are you trying to test deserialization because you discovered a quirk? Or are you trying to test your client with a dummy request/response?For the first, WCF uses DataContractSerializer to deserialize a response and return the payload.

Comment: For the second - just cheat! SOAP uses POST so you can create a simple HTTP API that returns the same text on every POST request. You could create an [HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netcore-3.1) that always returns the same response. Or you could create a bare .NET Core web app with [just a single endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.10

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos cheers for the comments; some data was missing in the deserialized objects and I'm TDD'ing my way to the fix based on a real copy of the XML from the 3rd party production server. I have a working HttpListener working in a test now that does as you describe and always serves the sample xml response. You can see the wip here https://github.com/SkillsFundingAgency/dfc-coursedirectory/commit/a2d3a8e1d822eec9278149f9b460b53e77a768d9#diff-d0a1b81c9474cd6cf5bbbd4b0470cff9R21 (this sha might go away soon).

Comment: @TimAbell WCF isn't broken. The generated client won't miss data- it *can't*. It *has* to follow the XSD and produce XML or objects that comply with it. That's a huge difference between XML and JSON - XML documents *must* comply with their XSD.  If you have issues with the response, you should ask about that. This is probably not about any WCF bug. The technology is used for 12 years after in real financial transactions. If there were problems, people would have noticed

Comment: So what's the *real* problem? If you suspect a deserialization issue, just use DataContractSerializer to deserialize a sample XML. What happens? What did you expect to get, what did you get?

Comment: The problem turned out to be with the `Reference.cs` file that Visual Studio had generated from the wsdl, it was to do with namespaces and the use of "Unqualified" `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]` attributes. I never suggested it was WCF itself that was broken. The problem was just somewhere in that area and WCF was making it hard to construct tests. I have a working branch now. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you'd like to post the httplistener suggestion as an answer I'll mark it as accepted as that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet. so I'll do as an answer. Donetwcf is a ongoing project, .Net Core doesn't support server WCF side only Client Side, as said this you only has to add your endpoint by adding a connected service using the urlacl that have you provided, if you are running a wcf service remember that you have to set up the pool in the iis manager, or you can do manually adding via netsh as microsoft provide.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http

there is a exe to test the service called WcfTestClient.exe where normally can be found in the visual studio folder as mine is : \Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

when you add the service to .net solution you will have to initialize as Client like this:
WCF_Client.MyClient ThisClient = new WCF_Client.MyClient();

you can create a string in the serverside and read it with the client and convert using JsonConvert instead of XML.

I believe what you are trying to do is a little overcomplicate when I just recommend you to use a ResAPI instead.

Comment: Thanks. I do not control the server I am connected to (question updated to make this clear) so the approaches you suggest with the [WcfTestClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe) or changing the service to JSON aren't available to me.

Comment: so you don't need that library, because .net core already support client side using System.ServiceModel. Just add it by connected services on the solution explorer it is the first down of your project.